# How to make migrations with django-south

Tags: django, django-south, database-migration

The application I'm developing is starting to need migration for the database schemas. I've thought about django-south, but since I have no experience with that kind of stuff I'm a bit lost, this is my situation:

Development code: latest models, I didn't keep track of what changes I've made to the models.

Production code: running code, has old models. We have the server configured so we can make deployments just with a git pull :)

How can I update the code in production (and the DB) without breaking anything? I saw about the `--initial` statement but I don't think it works for this case, and also for `convert_to_south` to fake a migrationhistory, but I still don't get what should I do. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imo it would be better to create versioning for your project and deploy it with something like [Fabric](http://lethain.com/deploying-django-with-fabric/). This will contain your production environment nicely.

There's no magic with south, just add south to the installed apps setting and run an initial schemamigration then run a fake migration (`migrate <app_name> --fake`) so south 'knows' the current state of your models. In future releases (that contain schema changes) you can run `schemamigration <app_name> --auto` and `migrate <app_name>` to update the models accordingly.

To keep your migrations in one place use the migrations setting in your settings file:

```
SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'app_name_1': 'project_name.migrations.page',
    'app_name_2': 'project_name.migrations.medialibrary',
}
```

Comment: Whare am I supposed to run those commands? on the development code or in the production server? :)

Comment: both if you want to control schemamigrations for both (or once per database)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to checkout the production version (to get the models back to production state), create an initial migration, copy that migration to your current development branch then create a schemamigration.